# Sonar analysis using multiple git branches in Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have setup Jenkins to automatically build several git branches of my project. The build also triggers Sonar analysis, as a post-build action.

The problem is that all branches point to the same Sonar project. I know that there is a sonar.branch property. Is it possible to have Jenkins automatically set sonar.branch property to the current git branch being built (without having to change project's pom.xml)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try adding `-Dsonar.branch.name=something` in the field MAVEN_OPTS in jenkins post-build action (Advanced configuration).

I don't know how to resolve `something`, since I don't know how you configure your jenkins job... but it will probably be something like [`$git.branch`](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+Sonar+on+Jenkins+Job#TriggeringSonaronJenkinsJob-TriggeringaSonarAnalysiswithMaven).

I didn't try, so i'm not sure it will work.

In a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline, the variable is `BRANCH_NAME`.

**P.S.**
While reading your question it's difficult to say if you are using maven or not to trigger sonar. If you are not using maven: [there is a `project properties` field in the Jenkins config where you can define `sonar.branch`](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+Sonar+on+Jenkins+Job#TriggeringSonaronJenkinsJob-TriggeringaSonarAnalysiswiththeSonarRunner).

Comment: I ended up using the approach you suggested, using different jobs for each branch. I do use Jenkins to trigger sonar, so I set the sonar.branch property accordingly for each job.

I think this has also the advantage that the build job is triggered only if a commit is made for this particular branch, and also you can create more fine-grained build schedule control/notifications for more important branches etc.

Comment: Not working for me :-(
I added $GIT_BRANCH in MAVEN_OPTS. still when I am building from some other branch through some other job - the dashboard showing coverage is changing to the results from the latest branch run. I want it to remain same for my branch.

Comment: Branch name will be experted either as env variable or script interpolation.

Comment: I think the `sonar.branch.name` property is only available in the commercial editions but not in the community edition.

Comment: @Datz, at the time this question was asked, 7 years ago, it was available in the Community Edition. You're correct that it is now only in Developer Edition and above.

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```
mvn sonar:sonar -U -Dsonar.branch.name=$BRANCH_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps you with the automated Jenkins execution, but to run a mvn sonar:sonar with the proper branch set, you can run the command (note the back-quotes), if you are in a Unix based environment:

```
mvn -Dsonar.branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` sonar:sonar
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use build parameters in order to specify the branch?

If yes, you can easily tell to Sonar which branch is it, juste add in config textarea:

```
sonar.branch=${branch}
```

Where branch is the name of the build parameter.

Comment: sonar community ed. 9.5.0 - I got this message "The 'sonar.branch' parameter is no longer supported. You should stop using it. Branch analysis is available in Developer Edition and above. See https://redirect.sonarsource.com/editions/developer.html for more information".

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this I generally use `-Dsonar.branch.name=${env.CHANGE_BRANCH}`