# How to get pr number of gitea at jenkins pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, gitea

I'm using gitea & jenkins & sonarqube combination now.

I need pr number of gitea for sonarqube pr comment but i don't know how to get pr number at jenkins pipeline.

I tried env variables like this.

`PR_ID=env.BRANCH_NAME.replace(/^PR-/, '')`

but there was no pr id...

So i checked just ${env.BRANCH_NAME} but i got just barnch name.

[image]

And i also tried env variable ${env.CHANGE_ID} but i got null. =(

(I'm using multibranch pipeline)

[image]

Is there any way to get pr number of gitea at jenkins pipeline...?

Answer (score 1):

If your Jenkins job is set on the develop branch, it branch name is `develop`

But you can try and, in said Jenkins job, [extract the branch merged into develop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70710720/6309) (a topic branch whose name should include a PR number), assuming the latest commit on develop is a merged commit.

From there, you can [pass it to sonarqube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45974278/6309).

```
-Dsonar.branch.name=${env.YOUR_VARIABLE}
```

---

The [OP gunyoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20456387/gunyoung) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370687/how-to-get-pr-number-of-gitea-at-jenkins-pipeline/74371026#comment131297666_74371026):

> I solve this problem by using your idea.
>
> I'm using this variable in Jenkinsfile and there is PR number.
>
> ```
>  GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE = sh(script: "git --no-pager show -s --format=%B ${env.GIT_COMMIT}", returnStdout: true).trim();
> ```
>
> So I make another variable using `substring` and I got just PR number.
>
> ```
> PR_ID = sh(script: "git --no-pager show -s --format=%B ${env.GIT_COMMIT}", returnStdout:true).trim().substring("${GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE}".indexOf('#')+1,"${GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE}".indexOf(')'));
> ```

Comment: Thank you!  
I solve this problem by using your idea. I'm using this variable in jenkinsfile and there is pr number.   
  
`GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE = sh(script: "git --no-pager show -s --format=%B ${env.GIT_COMMIT}", returnStdout: true).trim();`   
  
So i make another variable using substring and i got just pr number. =)   
  
`PR_ID = sh(script: "git --no-pager show -s --format=%B ${env.GIT_COMMIT}", returnStdout: true).trim().substring("${GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE}".indexOf('#')+1,"${GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE}".indexOf(')'));`

Comment: @gunyoung Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.